# Get a signed access token from thinktecture Identity server

Tags: oauth, thinktecture-ident-server

I am using Thinktecture Identityserver as a token issuer. I have it setup with a cert and am able to have it issue access tokens. The issue is that the tokens are not signed. Is there something in the ID server config that I need to setup?

Thanks.

Comment: Tokens  in Idsrv are always signed.